# ARKit capturedImage and snapshot are not same

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, snapshot

I am trying to get an image without 3D models and 3D models at the same time.

I use

`session.currentFrame!.capturedImage`

and then I take a snapshot using

`sceneView.snapshot()`

when both are done. the images look different, how do I get same image twice, one with and without 3D content. preferably in high res.

taken on iPhone 7s plus. so I am guessing the capturedImage and snapshot are using different lens?

[Session Captured Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSF3G.png)

[Scene Session Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3TOV.png)

If you see the images. the captured image cropped is not same. somehow the focal length or something is different in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

The [`displayTransformForOrientation:viewportSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransformfororientation) provides the transform that ARKit uses to map the `capturedImage` onto the view's background:

> This method creates an affine transform representing the rotation and
>   aspect-fit crop operations necessary to adapt the camera image to the
>   specified orientation and to the aspect ratio of the specified
>   viewport.

Answer (score -1):

Ask a specific question ;).
The `.snapshot()` is a capture of the sceneView with takes the whole screen, which is a different aspect ratio to the image. if you superpose your images you can see how they match.

so if you want the same, you need to crop the capturedImage yourself.

[image: superposed images]